# How to create an html structure in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/cristian-marius/pen/gOpoQam)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div id="container-list"></div>
```

**CODE jQuery:**

```
  var num = 10;
  var containerUl = $('<ul />'); 


  for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    var containerLi = containerUl.append('<li>'+ i +'</li>');
    containerLi.append(containerLi);
  }


  $('#container-list').html(containerUl);
```

I want to create an HTML structure with a jQuery function.

HTML structure new:

```
<ul>
 <li>
     <div class="qa-title">
         <h2>Bonorum et Malorum 6</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="qa-date-user">
         <span class="qa-date">10/25/2019;</span>
         <span class="qa-user">Asked by Sofia</span>
     </div>
     <div class="qa-question">
         <p><span>Q:></span>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque</p>
     </div>
     <div class="qa-answer">
         <p><span>A:</span>Merum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur</p>
     </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

basically, i would like to generate 10 such lines to populate my empty div

It seems a complicated structure and I do not know how to do it in js.

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: `html()` overwrites all previous content, so it's useless in a loop. Use `append()` instead: https://codepen.io/RoryMcCrossan/pen/xxGpQqx

Answer (score 0):

This code saves li's to variable and then put this HTML to container-list

```
var num = 10;
var ul = '<ul>';

for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    ul += '<li>'+ i +'</li>';
}

ul += '</ul>';

$('#container-list').html(ul);
```